# GithubのDependabotでプライベートリポジトリから取得しているComposerの依存関係のバージョンをチェックさせたい

Tags: composer

Githubのリポジトリにcomposerのライブラリを利用したプロジェクト（以下、便宜上「プロジェクトA」とします）を置いています。
このプロジェクトAのcomposerでは、依存関係としてgithubのプライベートリポジトリで公開しているライブラリ（以下、便宜上「ライブラリA」とします）およびいくつかのライブラリ（こちらはプライベートリポジトリではないです）を利用しています。
なお、プロジェクトAとライブラリAを公開しているGithubのアカウントは同一のものとなります。
このプロジェクトAでcomposerの依存関係としているライブラリ群のバージョンアップのチェックを目的にdependabotを利用したいと考えています。
一応下記のような内容のファイルを `.github/dependabot.yml` に設置したのですが、プライベートリポジトリで公開されているライブラリのバージョンチェックに失敗してしまいます。
`registories` の `composer-mylibrary` の設定がおかしいと思うのですが、どのように直したらよいかわからず困っています。
何かアドバイスをいただけますと幸いです。

```
version: 2
updates:
- package-ecosystem: composer
  directory: "/public/"
  registries:
    - composer-mylibrary
  schedule:
    interval: daily
registries:
  composer-mylibrary:
    type: composer-repository
    url: github.com
    username: x-access-token
    password: ${{secrets.GH_TOKEN}}
```

なお、Dependabotのログには下記のような内容が表示されています。
※ユーザー名やライブラリ名などは伏せ字にしています。

```
updater | 2023/09/20 03:36:39 INFO <job_xxxxx> Checking if exampleuser/library-a 1.0.2 needs updating
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:39 [020] GET https://repo.packagist.org:443/p2/exampleuser/library-a.json
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:39 [020] 404 https://repo.packagist.org:443/p2/exampleuser/library-a.json
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:43 [022] GET https://api.github.com:443/repos/exampleuser/library-a
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:43 [022] * authenticating github api request with token for api.github.com
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:43 [022] 404 https://api.github.com:443/repos/exampleuser/library-a
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:43 [024] GET https://github.com:443/exampleuser/library-a.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:43 [024] * authenticating git server request (host: github.com)
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:43 [024] * authenticating composer registry request (host: github.com)
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:43 [024] 200 https://github.com:443/exampleuser/library-a.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:43 [026] POST https://github.com:443/exampleuser/library-a.git/git-upload-pack
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:43 [026] * authenticating git server request (host: github.com)
  proxy | 2023/09/20 03:36:43 [026] 404 https://github.com:443/exampleuser/library-a.git/git-upload-pack
updater | 2023/09/20 03:36:44 INFO <job_xxxxx> Handled error whilst updating exampleuser/library-a: git_dependencies_not_reachable {:"dependency-urls"=>["git@github.com:exampleuser/library-a.git"]}
```

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。